# How to get the value from enum by a numeric key in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enums, react-proptypes

I have a `const` that is acting like `enum` in my case. And I need to get the value from it already on the `PropType call`.

So here is my `enum`:

```
const appearances = {
    1: 'ready',
    2: 'stroke',
    3: 'flat'
};
```

And the way I have tried to get the `value`:

```
Button.propTypes = {
  appearance: PropTypes.oneOf(Object.keys(appearances))
}
```

It seems that `oneOf()` only accepts `String` type `keys`, but I get a numeric value from my backend. Is there a way to do it?

So if I give the `key` of `1`, I would like to recieve a `value` of `ready`.

Comment: Use `String` like: String(2) => "2".

Comment: @MarkoSavic  I am sorry, but I do not quite understand your answer.

Comment: Try with `String` object `PropTypes.oneOf(String(Object.keys(appearances)))`

Comment: @MarkoSavic by doing that and giving the key `1` I get the following result: `1`, but expected result is `ready`

Comment: How about to use `bracket notation` instead oneOf?  `appearances[1] => ready` ?

Comment: And what would you replace with the number `1`. I need some kind of a key for that and I have tried `key` but I havent gotten it to work.

Comment: What's the reason you're trying to get a value using PropTypes? Since it is only used for typechecking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this like a bracket notation `appearances[x]`:

```
Button.propTypes = {
  appearance: appearances[PropTypes.oneOf(Object.keys(appearances))]
}
```

Comment: By doing that I still get the value of `1`

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question slightly. How about now? It should mix the simplicity of bracket notation with your `PropType` and `Object.keys()`